# Unable to encrypt plaintext to password

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, freeradius, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm trying enhance the current implementation of password hiding stated

Am I using it wrongly? As below is my code:

```
import hashlib
import binascii
def Encrypt_Pass(password, authenticator, secret):
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(secret+authenticator)
        return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(password.ljust
       (16,'\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))
result = Encrypt_Pass("abcd1","344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73","sharedsecret")
ciphertext = "6ed3a35440abe69b2e8698109b809932"#plaintext is cisco123
print result.encode("hex")
```

Result is shown below :

```
2509f347a7c5bde3977bb944ae0eb89a
```

As you can see the returned ciphertext DOES NOT match the encrypted password I capture ! Am I using the code wrongly? I verified that the plaintext password and shared key used are accurate.

Appreciate if someone could point me the right direction.

Comment: [MD5 isn't encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your authenticator is a hex string.  It needs to be converted to a binary string.

```
import hashlib
from binascii import a2b_hex

def Encrypt_Pass(password, authenticator, secret):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(secret + a2b_hex(authenticator))
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(password.ljust
       (16,'\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))

result = Encrypt_Pass("cisco123","344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73","sharedsecret")
ciphertext = "6ed3a35440abe69b2e8698109b809932"#plaintext is cisco123
print result.encode("hex")
```

Comment: can i ask why it has to be a binary string ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be but you have to be talking apples to apples.   The string "344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73" isn't really the authenticator.  It's the human readable hex representation of your authenticator.  It would be analogous to saying your authenticator was the word "hello" and then using the spanish word "hola" to try and authenticate with-- not going to work.  Your authenticator has to match.